# How to add 1 Month to DATE in an IF Statement?

Tags: excel, date

I am creating a personal spreadsheet in Excel. I have a countdown that counts the days until a specific date, at which point when it hits 0, I wish to add 1 **Calendar** month onto the specific set date, so for example...

---

*State 1*
Set Date    Days Until Set Date    

01/01/16     1

---

*State 2*
Set Date    Days Until Set Date

01/01/16    0   (Day hits 0, 1 calendar month is added)

---

*State 3*
Set Date    Days Until Set Date

02/01/16    31

---

My guess is that I would need to use an `IF` statement? I hope I have clearly explained my plans! Note: Each month would start on the 1st.

Comment: Define *add a month*. Do you mean *add 30 days*, or *add a calendar month, meaning add 30 days if it's September, April, June, or November, or 31 if it's another month except February, in which case add the number of days in February depending on whether it's a leap year or not*? Or something else?

Comment: This would be adding a calendar month.

Comment: Don't tell me in the comments; [edit] to include it in your question. Also, is the day of the month always the first?

Comment: something like: `=IF(TODAY()>A1,A1-TODAY(),DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,DAY(A1))-TODAY())`??? having `DATE(2005,13,4)` will show 2006-01-04... this way "adding" one month should be no problen... or did i got you wrong?

Comment: use the [EDATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edate-function-1586b161-4361-4a6d-939b-9d96eae962a8) like`=edate(a1, b1=0)`

Comment: Using the EDATE function like so `=IF(M21=0,EDATE(H21,1),"")` spurs out a random number, 42515 to be exact.

Comment: ... and 42515 just happens to be 25-May-2016 when formatted as a date.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution.

By using the `EDATE` function, I was able to add 1 calendar month to the set date, and by changing the cell type from `General` to `Short Date`, fixed the random number spur issue for me.

So, in my case

`=IF(M21=0,EDATE(H21,1),"Still waiting!")`

Answer (score 0):

That was an interesting one to think through.  The way I would set this up is that you have one cell that is used to have today's date that the other formulas drive off of.

So say in cell A1 you have the current date with `rounddown(now(),0)`.

Then you'll have three columns for each item you want to keep track of.  The first column will be the date that this happens on each month, the next occurrence, and they days until

|---Set Date---|----Next Date-----|----Days Until -----|

____1__________5/1/16_________29________

Now, assuming that my first set date is in cell A3, my next date is cell B3, and the Days Until is in C3 you would use the following inputs:

A3:  `1`

B3:  `=DATE(IF(MONTH(A1)=12,YEAR(A1)+1,YEAR(A1)),IF(DAY(A1)<A3,MONTH(A1),IF(MONTH(A1)+1>12,1,MONTH(A1)+1)),A3)`

C3:  `=ROUNDDOWN(B3-A1,0)`

This will correctly increase the year on the next date if you are in December.

Comment: Thank you  for your detailed explanation, while I have not used this method, I have in turn found an alternative solution which I have posted as an answer. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Also, this seems to add 2 months onto the current date?

Comment: It shouldn't.  Built it out in a workbook and worked fine.